# After ipython installation: iptest: command not found

Tags: ipython

this is my first time working with IPython, I think I installed it correctly but I found a problem when running the iptest. I must mention that if I run ipython in the terminal it runs without errors, but I just want to make that everything it's fine with the installation.

Installation:

```
$ pip install ipython[all]
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython[all] in /usr/lib/python2.7/site-packages
  Installing extra requirements: 'all'
Cleaning up...

$ iptest
bash: iptest: command not found
```

Thanks for your time.

Comment: Did you try my solution? is it working now?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same problem on one of my computers.
This is a computer without virtualenv.
So all pip packages are at system level.

First I tried to install ipython[all], just in case something missing.

```
 $ sudo pip install ipython[all]
Requirement already satisfied (use --upgrade to upgrade): ipython[all] in /usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages
  Installing extra requirements: 'all'
Cleaning up...
```

Then I installed nose specifically:

```
$ sudo pip install nose
```

After installing nose, It still didn't work. So I upgraded everything to the current version:

```
$ sudo pip install --upgrade ipython[all]
```

Which solved the problem for me.

Now `$ iptest` installed and run correctly.